# Airflow add operator link using task instance's try number

Tags: airflow

I'm following this [example](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/define_extra_link.html#add-or-override-links-to-existing-operators) for adding an operator link, visible when viewing a particular task instance.

The below get_link function (taken from the example) is getting the dag_id and task_id from the operator object, is there any way I can access the try_number to include within the formatted string as well? I tried using the macro `{{ ti.try_number }}`, but the macro isn't accessible, as it just prints out as "{{ ti.try_number }}":

```
def get_link(self, operator, dttm):
        return 'www.logs_link.com/search="{dag_id}-{task_id}-{execution_date}-{try_number}"'.format(
            dag_id=operator.dag_id,
            task_id=operator.task_id,
            execution_date=dttm,
            try_number="{{ ti.try_number }}"
        )
```

Desired log prefix examples:

```
"dagname-taskname-2020-01-01T00:00:00+00:00-1: LOG MESSAGE"
"dagname-taskname-2020-01-01T00:00:00+00:00-1: LOG MESSAGE"
"dagname-taskname-2020-01-01T00:00:00+00:00-2: LOG MESSAGE"
"dagname-taskname-2020-01-01T00:00:00+00:00-2: LOG MESSAGE"
```

Comment: why do you need this ? `dag_id-task_id-execution_date` gives you a unique value for the path.

Comment: When we're backfilling data, the execution date of multiple runs of the dag id and task id combination is the same, e.g. 2016-01-01T00:00:00+00:00
So it would be useful to be able to group logs based on try number.

Comment: sorry but I don't understand how backfill related to try number. Could you please edit the question and provide more information about the actual use case?

Comment: Well, if it's backfilling from an earlier date, it will set the execution date as YYYY-MM-DDT00:00:00+00:00 so, if the backfill job retries, the same execution date will be used and therefore you can't differentiate between tries in the logs unless they have the try number on the end